# How to set time zone for a user after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using ruby on **rails-3.2 with psql.**

My problem is : When a login user create or update any content the date-time display is of server but not of his local time-zone. My users are in whole world. So I can't set specific time-zone.

**In application.rb file my time-zone is default.**

**For login I'm using devise gem.**

```
I can find the names of the ActiveSupport time zones by doing:

ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

**What I want is as soon as user login to my website I locate his time-zone.**

After some googling I have find the time zone by javascript

```
var timezone=String(new Date());
var zone = timezone.substring(timezone.indexOf('G'),timezone.indexOf('G')+8).trim();
```

It gives me GMT+0530

Now open rails console and write :

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all

[(GMT-11:00) American Samoa, (GMT-11:00) International Date Line West, (GMT-11:00) Midway Island, (GMT-10:00) Hawaii, (GMT-09:00) Alaska, (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada), (GMT-08:00) Tijuana, (GMT-07:00) Arizona, (GMT-07:00) Chihuahua, (GMT-07:00) Mazatlan, (GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada), (GMT-06:00) Central America, (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada), (GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, (GMT-06:00) Mexico City, (GMT-06:00) Monterrey, (GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan, (GMT-05:00) Bogota, (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada), (GMT-05:00) Indiana (East), (GMT-05:00) Lima, (GMT-05:00) Quito, (GMT-04:30) Caracas, (GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada), (GMT-04:00) Georgetown, (GMT-04:00) La Paz, (GMT-04:00) Santiago, (GMT-03:30) Newfoundland, (GMT-03:00) Brasilia, (GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires, (GMT-03:00) Greenland, (GMT-02:00) Mid-Atlantic, (GMT-01:00) Azores, (GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Is., (GMT+00:00) Casablanca, (GMT+00:00) Dublin, (GMT+00:00) Edinburgh, (GMT+00:00) Lisbon, (GMT+00:00) London, (GMT+00:00) Monrovia, (GMT+00:00) UTC, (GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, (GMT+01:00) Belgrade, (GMT+01:00) Berlin, (GMT+01:00) Bern, (GMT+01:00) Bratislava, (GMT+01:00) Brussels, (GMT+01:00) Budapest, (GMT+01:00) Copenhagen, (GMT+01:00) Ljubljana, (GMT+01:00) Madrid, (GMT+01:00) Paris, (GMT+01:00) Prague, (GMT+01:00) Rome, (GMT+01:00) Sarajevo, (GMT+01:00) Skopje, (GMT+01:00) Stockholm, (GMT+01:00) Vienna, (GMT+01:00) Warsaw, (GMT+01:00) West Central Africa, (GMT+01:00) Zagreb, (GMT+02:00) Athens, (GMT+02:00) Bucharest, (GMT+02:00) Cairo, (GMT+02:00) Harare, (GMT+02:00) Helsinki, (GMT+02:00) Istanbul, (GMT+02:00) Jerusalem, (GMT+02:00) Kyiv, (GMT+02:00) Pretoria, (GMT+02:00) Riga, (GMT+02:00) Sofia, (GMT+02:00) Tallinn, (GMT+02:00) Vilnius, (GMT+03:00) Baghdad, (GMT+03:00) Kuwait, (GMT+03:00) Minsk, (GMT+03:00) Nairobi, (GMT+03:00) Riyadh, (GMT+03:30) Tehran, (GMT+04:00) Abu Dhabi, (GMT+04:00) Baku, (GMT+04:00) Moscow, (GMT+04:00) Muscat, (GMT+04:00) St. Petersburg, (GMT+04:00) Tbilisi, (GMT+04:00) Volgograd, (GMT+04:00) Yerevan, (GMT+04:30) Kabul, (GMT+05:00) Islamabad, (GMT+05:00) Karachi, (GMT+05:00) Tashkent, (GMT+05:30) Chennai, (GMT+05:30) Kolkata, (GMT+05:30) Mumbai, (GMT+05:30) New Delhi, (GMT+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura, (GMT+05:45) Kathmandu, (GMT+06:00) Almaty, (GMT+06:00) Astana, (GMT+06:00) Dhaka, (GMT+06:00) Ekaterinburg, (GMT+06:30) Rangoon, (GMT+07:00) Bangkok, (GMT+07:00) Hanoi, (GMT+07:00) Jakarta, (GMT+07:00) Novosibirsk, (GMT+08:00) Beijing, (GMT+08:00) Chongqing, (GMT+08:00) Hong Kong, (GMT+08:00) Krasnoyarsk, (GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, (GMT+08:00) Perth, (GMT+08:00) Singapore, (GMT+08:00) Taipei, (GMT+08:00) Ulaan Bataar, (GMT+08:00) Urumqi, (GMT+09:00) Irkutsk, (GMT+09:00) Osaka, (GMT+09:00) Sapporo, (GMT+09:00) Seoul, (GMT+09:00) Tokyo, (GMT+09:30) Adelaide, (GMT+09:30) Darwin, (GMT+10:00) Brisbane, (GMT+10:00) Canberra, (GMT+10:00) Guam, (GMT+10:00) Hobart, (GMT+10:00) Melbourne, (GMT+10:00) Port Moresby, (GMT+10:00) Sydney, (GMT+10:00) Yakutsk, (GMT+11:00) New Caledonia, (GMT+11:00) Vladivostok, (GMT+12:00) Auckland, (GMT+12:00) Fiji, (GMT+12:00) Kamchatka, (GMT+12:00) Magadan, (GMT+12:00) Marshall Is., (GMT+12:00) Solomon Is., (GMT+12:00) Wellington, (GMT+13:00) Nuku'alofa, (GMT+13:00) Samoa, (GMT+14:00) Tokelau Is.]
```

If I set

```
Time.zone = -11 
Time.zone 
(GMT-11:00) American Samoa
```

How can I set

**Time.zone = 0530**

```
It gives me error ArgumentError: Invalid Timezone: 344
```

Comment: Related to [Determining a web user's time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone)

Comment: Add time zone to user model, see railscast - http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1 - display times using I18n.localize method - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats